# Remove '0' (Number) from DateTime Month and Day (String)

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Can anybody tell me the best approach or solution on how I would do the following?

I have a DateTime (as String) in following format:

```
string test = "21.12.2013";
```

How could I now remove all zero's from the month and day but still 'keep' the DateTime Logic:

```
//Example 1
string input = "06.10.2013" // 6th October
string output = "6.10.2013" //only remove '0' from the day

//Example 2
string input = "01.09.2012" // 1st September
string output = "1.9.2012" //remove from month and day

//Example 3
string input = "20.10.2011" // 20th October
string output = "20.10.2011" //should (must) stay!
```

I can also parse to `DateTime` if that would be make it easier but yeah I hope you got my idea...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: That's display and doesn't influence the way it's saved. Look for your correct representation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing your string into `DateTime` and getting it back to string using `ToString` with desired patter seems to be the easiest way to go:

```
public static string GetRidOfZeros(string input)
{
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return dt.ToString("d.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Little testing, with your sample data:

```
var inputs = new List<string> { "06.10.2013", "01.09.2012", "20.10.2011" };
var outputs = new List<string> { "6.10.2013", "1.9.2012","20.10.2011" };

if(outputs.SequenceEqual(inputs.Select(d => GetRidOfZeros(d))))
    Console.WriteLine("Output is OK");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Collections does not match.");
```

Prints `Output is OK`.

Comment: Thx very much, I totally forgot bout `ToString("d.M.yyyy")` :(

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Parse(input).ToString("d.M.yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, parsing to `DateTime` first would probably make things easier, since then you can just use:

```
myDateTime.ToString("d.M.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you parse it you can use ToString to format it any way you like:

```
var date = "06.10.2013";

DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var noZerosHere = parsed.ToString("d.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score -1):

A decent "catch-all" method (that will work not just on `DateTime` but ANY kind of string) would be to split the string up, take out leading zeroes and then put the pieces back together again.

```
string input = "01.09.2012";
string[] values = input.Split(".");
string[] modifiedValues = values.Select(x => x.TrimStart('0');
string output = String.Join(".", modifiedValues);
```

You can adjust the delimiters for different representations of DateTime, e.g. those that use slashes (01/09/2012) or are written in a different order.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? Don't you trust .NET's built-in DateTime?

Comment: IMO it's about "removing leading zeroes from substrings" as opposed to "reformatting a `DateTime`". I'd say it was nice to give a pure string manipulation answer, even though in this particular case `ParseExact` and `ToString` do the job too.

Comment: The title says "Remove '0' (Number) from DateTime Month and Day" so it is about reformatting a `DateTime`. Although your method probably works it's not really good advice.